# R - Scraping - rvest error : Subscript out of bound

Tags: r, screen-scraping, rvest

I am trying to loop through a list of horsenumber, with the base url pasted after (horseno=).
However, many of the time I either get back Subscript out of Bound error, or return a character(0).

```
library(rvest)
library(tidyverse)

horsenumber <- c("S385" "T436" "B016" "V102" "B121" "A370" "V026" "V107" "V086" "A082" "T267" "B059" "T118" "V077" "S393" "T230" "A061" "B387" "T370" "B165" "B326"
     [22] "B317" "B159" "B353" "T029" "T233" "A357" "A334" "A235" "T412" "V074" "B133" "T022" "A195" "T253" "A233" "V338" "B182" "A071" "V407" "B197" "B421"
     [43] "A427" "T282" "A359" "A069" "A097" "A351" "S397" "A305" "T112" "V334" "S204" "P421" "S277" "B141" "A333" "T380" "A005" "A189" "A314" "V381" "S420"
     [64] "A419" "V243" "A284" "S388" "A125" "B370" "A408" "A057" "A086" "B242" "A424" "B292" "T388" "V072" "V250" "A177" "T134" "A067" "A074" "A417" "B265"
     [85] "B170" "T419" "T389" "B080" "B300" "V336" "B119" "B204" "B144" "B260" "B350" "B056" "A150" "B209" "T200" "B149" "B249" "T349")

data <- lapply(paste0('http://racing.hkjc.com/racing/information/english/horse/horse.aspx?horseno=', horsenumber),
                function(url){
                      horsename <- url %>% read_html() %>% 
                        html_nodes(".title_text") %>% 
                        html_text()
                      horsename
                      age <- url %>% read_html() %>% 
                        html_nodes("td tr:nth-child(1) td:nth-child(2) span") %>% 
                        html_text()
                      age
                      sex <- url %>% read_html() %>% 
                        html_nodes("tr:nth-child(2) td:nth-child(2) span") %>% 
                        html_text()
                      sex
                      rhistory <- url %>% read_html() %>% 
                        html_nodes("tr:nth-child(6) td:nth-child(2) span.table_eng_text") %>% 
                        html_text()
                      rhistory
                      r10day <- url %>% read_html() %>% 
                        html_nodes("tr:nth-child(7) td:nth-child(2) span.table_eng_text") %>% 
                        html_text()
                      r10day
                      rating <- url %>% read_html() %>% 
                        html_nodes("tr:nth-child(3) td:nth-child(4) .table_eng_text") %>% 
                        html_text()
                      rating
                      data <- rbind(horsename,age,sex,rhistory,r10day,rating)
                      rbind(data)
                    })
```

In addition to that, I tried to use the following to scrape that particular table and turn it to dataframe for data mining. However, I also received Error in .[[6]] : subscript out of bounds.

```
horse_info <- page %>%
  html_nodes('table') %>%
  .[6] %>%
  html_table(fill=TRUE)
horse_info
```

Much appreciated

Comment: Does the website use JavaScript to populate HTML elements (like tables)? In such cases, rvest will fail because the appropriate JavaScript event needed to trigger the HTML element is not invoked when trying to scrape using rvest.

Comment: But then occassionally the correct scraping result did show up. It's just not happening all the time. Most of the time it's returning with subscript out of bound or character(0)

Comment: I have encountered websites with different DOM elements and structure on different pages (even though visually you couldn't tell the difference). I suspect this happens when companies hire different developers without proper communication established between the developers. Can you manually check 2 pages, one where scraping is successful and 1 where it is not, to see if the DOM is consistent?

Comment: If @Chaos is right, the splashr package might be useful here: https://github.com/hrbrmstr/splashr

Comment: Problem resolved with RSelenium.

Answer (score 0):

Here is an approach that you can consider :

```
library(RSelenium)
library(rvest)

port <- as.integer(4444L + rpois(lambda = 1000, 1))
rd <- rsDriver(chromever = "105.0.5195.52", browser = "chrome", port = port)
remDr <- rd$client

base_url <- "http://racing.hkjc.com/racing/information/english/horse/horse.aspx?horseno="


horsenumber <- c("S385", "T436", "B016", "V102", "B121", "A370", "V026", "V107", "V086", "A082", 
                 "T267", "B059", "T118", "V077", "S393", "T230", "A061", "B387", "T370", "B165", "B326",
                 "B317", "B159", "B353", "T029", "T233", "A357", "A334", "A235", "T412", "V074",
                 "B133", "T022", "A195", "T253", "A233", "V338", "B182", "A071", "V407", "B197", "B421",
                 "A427", "T282", "A359", "A069", "A097", "A351", "S397", "A305", "T112", "V334",
                 "S204", "P421", "S277", "B141", "A333", "T380", "A005", "A189", "A314", "V381", "S420",
                 "A419", "V243", "A284", "S388", "A125", "B370", "A408", "A057", "A086", "B242", 
                 "A424", "B292", "T388", "V072", "V250", "A177", "T134", "A067", "A074", "A417", "B265",
                 "B170", "T419", "T389", "B080", "B300", "V336", "B119", "B204", "B144", "B260",
                 "B350", "B056", "A150", "B209", "T200", "B149", "B249", "T349")

nb_Horse <- length(horsenumber)
list_Tables <- list()

for(i in 1 : nb_Horse)
{
  print(i)
  complete_url <- paste0(base_url, horsenumber[i])
  remDr$navigate(complete_url)
  Sys.sleep(10)
  html_Content <- remDr$getPageSource()[[1]]
  list_Tables[[i]] <- read_html(html_Content) %>% html_table()
}
```